# Finite Blaschke Product

Tags: complex-analysis

I have recently encountered this problem in my complex analysis course:

Let $f\colon\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ be a finite Blaschke product, say $f(z)=z\cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^N\dfrac{z-a_i}{1-\overline{a_i}z}$ where $a_1,\cdots,a_N\in \mathbb{D}.$ Let $0<r<1$ and $W$ be the connected component of $f^{-1}(\mathbb{D}_r(0))$ containing $0$. Show that there exist constants $0< r_1\leq r_2<1$ (which only depend on $r$ and $N$) such that $\mathbb{D}_{r_1}(0)\subset W\subset \mathbb{D}_{r_2}(0).$

In fact, every proper holomorphic map from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ with $f(0)=0$ and $deg(f)\leq N+1$ is of the above form. So I reduce the original problem to the above one. Can anyone provide some suggestions about it? Thanks!!